# RDS access from my own computer using apache server

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, wamp, amazon-rds

Hi guys i m trying to access my RDS instance from my computer using apache in wamp after fiddling around i found out about the security group i checked the security group and made it all traffic all ports all ips 0.0.0.0/0 i even tried to make it my ip but when i tried to run a script in my computer the script is 

`<?php
    $conn = new mysqli("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com","xxxxxxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxx");
    if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "yess";
    }
?>`

this gave me error "Connection failed: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. "
what to do? any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you enable the "publicly accessible" flag when creating the database?

Comment: Is it Centos? do you have SeLinux enabled? Then check   httpd_can_network_connect and httpd_can_network_connect_db:  should be set as 1 for remote database access.

Comment: Mark b u were right it was not set i modified the instance and made it publicly accessible.....thanks a ton mark B :-)                                             PS U have to reboot the instance to apply the changes ...